# Pick Video And Pics from photo gallary

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using assets Library to pick photos from photo gallery.Now i need to pick Video.
I make the following change in the code.

// Get count

```
ALAssetsGroup *g = (ALAssetsGroup*)[self.assetGroups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[g setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allAssets]];
```

then I saw there a thumbnail of video is showing. How i add the play button image on it.for thats why its look like appearance as video.I am using example of ELCImagePicker in github.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the fact that it's a video yourself. `ALAssetsLibrary` gives you access to the library and makes it easy to get thumbnails for display but after that it's up to you to use and display that information. So, you can add an icon image over the thumbnail you display and handle taps to perform a different action than you do for images.